# C++ error with INPUT class (Stack around the variable was corrupted.)

Tags: c++

i have error "Stack around the variable 'inp1L' was corrupted."

here is a piece of code

```
    INPUT inp1L[4];
    memset(inp1L, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp1L[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1L[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1L[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1L[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1L[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp1L[1].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
    inp1L[2].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp1L[3].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
```

i will be very grateful for the help

**upd**

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dinput.h>

int main()
{
    INPUT inp1[2];
    memset(inp1, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp1[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1[1] = inp1[0];
    inp1[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1[0].ki.wScan = inp1[1].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

    INPUT inp1L[4];
    memset(inp1L, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp1L[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1L[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1L[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1L[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1L[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1L[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp1L[1].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
    inp1L[2].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp1L[3].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

        INPUT inp1LD[6];
        memset(inp1LD, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp1LD[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LD[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LD[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LD[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LD[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LD[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LD[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1LD[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1LD[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1LD[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1LD[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1LD[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1LD[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp1LD[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp1LD[2].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
        inp1LD[3].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp1LD[4].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp1LD[5].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

            INPUT inp1LDR[8];
            memset(inp1LDR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
            inp1LD[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[7].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[6].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[7].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp1LD[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp1LD[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp1LD[3].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
            inp1LD[4].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp1LD[5].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp1LD[6].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp1LD[7].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

        INPUT inp1LR[6];
        memset(inp1LR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp1LR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1LR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1LR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1LR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1LR[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1LR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1LR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1LR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp1LR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp1LR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
        inp1LR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp1LR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp1LR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

    INPUT inp1D[4];
    memset(inp1D, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp1D[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1D[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1D[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1D[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1D[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1D[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1D[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1D[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1D[0].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
    inp1D[1].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
    inp1D[2].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
    inp1D[3].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

        INPUT inp1DR[6];
        memset(inp1DR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp1DR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1DR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1DR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1DR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1DR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1DR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp1DR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1DR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1DR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp1DR[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1DR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1DR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp1DR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp1DR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp1DR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
        inp1DR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp1DR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp1DR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

    INPUT inp1R[4];
    memset(inp1R, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp1R[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1R[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1R[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1R[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp1R[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1R[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp1R[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1R[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp1R[0].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
    inp1R[1].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
    inp1R[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
    inp1R[3].ki.wScan = DIK_1;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    INPUT inp2[2];
    memset(inp2, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp2[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2[1] = inp2[0];
    inp2[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2[0].ki.wScan = inp2[1].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

    INPUT inp2L[4];
    memset(inp2L, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp2L[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2L[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2L[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2L[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2L[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2L[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2L[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2L[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2L[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp2L[1].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
    inp2L[2].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp2L[3].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

        INPUT inp2LD[6];
        memset(inp2LD, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp2LD[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LD[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LD[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LD[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LD[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LD[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LD[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2LD[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2LD[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2LD[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2LD[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2LD[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2LD[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp2LD[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp2LD[2].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
        inp2LD[3].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp2LD[4].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp2LD[5].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

            INPUT inp2LDR[8];
            memset(inp2LDR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
            inp2LDR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[7].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp2LDR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp2LDR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp2LDR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp2LDR[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp2LDR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp2LDR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp2LDR[6].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp2LDR[7].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp2LDR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp2LDR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp2LDR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp2LDR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
            inp2LDR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp2LDR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp2LDR[6].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp2LDR[7].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

        INPUT inp2LR[6];
        memset(inp2LR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp2LR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2LR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2LR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2LR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2LR[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2LR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2LR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2LR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp2LR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp2LR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
        inp2LR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp2LR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp2LR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

    INPUT inp2D[4];
    memset(inp2D, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp2D[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2D[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2D[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2D[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2D[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2D[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2D[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2D[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2D[0].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
    inp2D[1].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
    inp2D[2].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
    inp2D[3].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

        INPUT inp2DR[6];
        memset(inp2DR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp2DR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2DR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2DR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2DR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2DR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2DR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp2DR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2DR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2DR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp2DR[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2DR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2DR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp2DR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp2DR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp2DR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
        inp2DR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp2DR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp2DR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

    INPUT inp2R[4];
    memset(inp2R, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp2R[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2R[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2R[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2R[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp2R[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2R[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp2R[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2R[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp2R[0].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
    inp2R[1].ki.wScan = DIK_2;
    inp2R[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
    inp2R[3].ki.wScan = DIK_2;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    INPUT inp3[2];
    memset(inp3, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp3[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3[1] = inp3[0];
    inp3[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3[0].ki.wScan = inp3[1].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

    INPUT inp3L[4];
    memset(inp3L, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp3L[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3L[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3L[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3L[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3L[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3L[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3L[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3L[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3L[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp3L[1].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
    inp3L[2].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
    inp3L[3].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

    INPUT inp3LD[6];
        memset(inp3LD, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp3LD[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LD[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LD[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LD[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LD[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LD[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LD[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3LD[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3LD[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3LD[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3LD[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3LD[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3LD[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp3LD[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp3LD[2].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
        inp3LD[3].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp3LD[4].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp3LD[5].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

            INPUT inp3LDR[8];
            memset(inp3LDR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
            inp3LDR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[7].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp3LDR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp3LDR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp3LDR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp3LDR[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp3LDR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp3LDR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp3LDR[6].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp3LDR[7].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp3LDR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp3LDR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp3LDR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp3LDR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
            inp3LDR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp3LDR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp3LDR[6].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp3LDR[7].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

        INPUT inp3LR[6];
        memset(inp3LR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp3LR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3LR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3LR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3LR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3LR[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3LR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3LR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3LR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp3LR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp3LR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
        inp3LR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
        inp3LR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp3LR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

    INPUT inp3D[4];
    memset(inp3D, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp3D[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3D[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3D[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3D[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3D[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3D[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3D[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3D[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3D[0].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
    inp3D[1].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
    inp3D[2].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
    inp3D[3].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

        INPUT inp3DR[6];
        memset(inp3DR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
        inp3DR[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3DR[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3DR[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3DR[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3DR[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3DR[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp3DR[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3DR[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3DR[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        inp3DR[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3DR[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3DR[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        inp3DR[0].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp3DR[1].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp3DR[2].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
        inp3DR[3].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
        inp3DR[4].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
        inp3DR[5].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

    INPUT inp3R[4];
    memset(inp3R, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
    inp3R[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3R[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3R[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3R[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inp3R[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3R[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    inp3R[2].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3R[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inp3R[0].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
    inp3R[1].ki.wScan = DIK_3;
    inp3R[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
    inp3R[3].ki.wScan = DIK_3;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    printf("Waiting for input...");
    _getch();
    printf("\nStart in 5 seconds");
    Sleep(1000);



   SendInput(2, inp1, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(250);
   SendInput(2, inp2, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(250);
   SendInput(2, inp3, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(250);
   SendInput(2, inp3, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(250);
   SendInput(2, inp3, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(250);
   SendInput(2, inp2, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(250);
   SendInput(2, inp1, sizeof(INPUT));
   Sleep(500);
```

im really sorry for this kind of mess... but i need help. for first things he swears at inp1L and inp1LD

***upd - error was found*** at

```
            INPUT inp1LDR[8];
            memset(inp1LDR, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
            inp1LD[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[7].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inp1LD[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            inp1LD[4].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[5].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[6].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[7].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            inp1LD[0].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp1LD[1].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp1LD[2].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp1LD[3].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
            inp1LD[4].ki.wScan = DIK_LEFTARROW;
            inp1LD[5].ki.wScan = DIK_DOWNARROW;
            inp1LD[6].ki.wScan = DIK_RIGHTARROW;
            inp1LD[7].ki.wScan = DIK_1;
```

inp1LD > inp1LDR (all because of inattentiveness)

Comment: you only set valid entries of *inp1L*, this is not in that piece of code you corrupt your stack. Anyway the `|=` produce an undefined behavior because you do that on a non  initialized value, do `=` rather than `=`

Comment: That error message only gives the _approximate_ memory location corrupted.

Comment: oh, okay and thanks for a comment. i can post full code but you wont like it because its big and ugly. but I will try xd

Comment: I changed |= to =, he still swears, but thanks for the advice

Comment: I just tried to build and run your code, I am using VS2017, it is giving this compiler error error C4789: buffer 'inp1LD' of size 240 bytes will be overrun; 2 bytes will be written starting at offset 240. I am trying to understand why the compiler is saying so. Seems like the problem you are facing during run time compiler is able to figure it out.

Comment: You are assigning to `inp1LD` instead of `inp1LDR`.  There may be other problems.  A better way to write this code is to initialise your arrays via initialiser lists.

Comment: @PaulSanders, please could you show it via quote, because im dont understand where i made a mistake

Comment: oh, yes, sorry, i will try that
***upd*** YES, thank you very much. i am really very inattentive. thank you all for your help guys

Comment: @PaulSanders could you please help how i can mark your comment as right answer and close this question? im new here and cant find how to do this...

Comment: You can't accept comments, only upvote them.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Garreth why is it marked as C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you use memset, you have to do the math for the number of bytes you set. For example:

```
INPUT inp1LDR[8];    
memset(inp1LDR, 0, 8*sizeof(INPUT));
```

otherwise only the first element of your array will be initialized with zero values.

With that you can use bit-operations like `|=`

Comment: There are better ways of doing this.

Comment: i already thought about it but no one said anything and i thought that this didnt particularly affect, but thanks a lot for the advice)

Comment: Well, I can give you more hints if you show us the structure. You can avoid entirely the memsets, use initializer lists for more elegance. C++11 has a lot of nice ways doing this much more convenient.